# hide console on iPhone in jQuery Mobiel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a web app developed with jQuery Mobile. It works fine but on the iPhone there is an additional "console" bar above the title:
[image]

My question is: how can I make it disappear?

thank you for your help

Micha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console can be deactivated in the "settings" app of your iDevice, in "safari", "developper" sub menu

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html